# Neural Networks unmatched on MNIST?

Tags: neural-networks, history

I remember reading or hearing a claim that at any point in time since the publication of the MNIST dataset, it has never happened that a method not based on neural networks was the best given the state of science of that point in time.

Is this claim true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the relevant [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database):

> The original creators of the database keep a list of some of the methods tested on it.[7] In their original paper, they use a support-vector machine to get an error rate of 0.8%

Feel free to look up that original paper, but to me the quote strongly suggests that the first record holder was a support vector machine.

---

#### Edit

As liori points out the quote is misleading: In the original paper Yann LeCun et al. actually tried a slew of methods and one version of ConvNet scored best (0.7).

But according to the [MNIST-webpage](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/), after that initial paper, DeCoste and Scholkopf, MLJ 2002, reached an error of 0.56 with a SVM. So if that webpage is complete, the claim is still false.

Comment: Seems like the paper referenced in [5] (http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf) on Wikipedia states both the V-SVM result of 0.8 and the boosted LeNet-4 result of 0.7, so… not in this case.

Comment: [5] is actually this link: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ ,but you still seem to be right.

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the original question, which was supposedly asking if any other technique surpassed NNs on the MNIST task, not if before NNs there was a technique that performed better than them, as the OP wrote "**since** the publication of the MNIST dataset, it has never happened".